# How to set client in useQuery Apollo in ReactJs

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo

I want to change the url from what is set in the context. Here I want to use useQuery, when using Query I successfully set a new url client, as follows.

```
const onlineDocumentServiceClient = new ApolloClient({
  uri: process.env.REACT_APP_GQL_ODS
});

<Query query={QUERY} client={onlineDocumentServiceClient}>
```

I do not understand what if using useQuery can I do as Query does. I found it in https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/data/queries/#executing-queries-manually the use of query can also be set by the client

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just pass it in as an option:

```
const { data, loading, refetch } = useQuery(MY_QUERY, { client: myClient });
```

Comment: But why is that looping so much? if not using the client option, it's not looping.

Comment: Not sure what you mean?

Comment: I mean, there are repeated requests like https://ibb.co/fY3y2XP. Whereas if I don't use "client" but the code is like this "const { data, loading, refetch } = useQuery(MY_QUERY)" it doesn't repeat the request.

Comment: The request will be run every time the function component is called. If you don't pass in the client, where is the client coming from? The only other way would be to use an ApolloProvider, in which case you don't need to pass the client in at all unless it's a different client.

Comment: In my case, backend there are 2 different urls. 1 I put it on index.js (ApolloProvider), and other url (less accessible) I want to implement in useQuery directly. Are there any tips for my problem?

Comment: To pass in the client directly, as shown in the answer. If your client is endlessly looping requests, it's a problem with your React component, not the query. If you open another question and post the code I can help you debug it.

Comment: I found that the creation of the client can't be done inside the React component, it causes the hooking mechanism to repeat itself. If you create the client outside of the component then call it on your useQuery hook it should help the issue go away.